# Cуммирование рядов. Эффект потери точности

Tags: c++, c, числа-с-плавающей-точкой, эффекты

Это программа для вычисления суммы ряда для экспоненты. Учитель задал 2 вопроса: Кто виноват и Что делать ?

Кто виноват? Эффект потери точности(Нужно пояснить, откуда эффект потери точности)

Что делать ? (Нужно исправить программу так ,чтобы на отрицательных х выдавал exp(x), как в таблице)

Заранее Спасибо! [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
double my_exp(double x);
int main(void)
{
    double a,x;
    scanf("%le",&x);
    a=my_exp(x);
    printf("%le",(double)a);
    return 0;}
    
double my_exp(double x)
{
  double sum=1.0, h, eps=1.e-16; int i=2;
h=x;
do{
    sum+=h;
    h*=x/i;
    i++;}
while( fabs(h)>eps );
return sum;
}
```

Comment: А мы по условию *ЗНАЕМ*, что это экспонента, или нет?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь , то да

Comment: Тогда считаем для положительного `x` - там точность вполне приличная, а потом вычисляем обратное... А причина проблем в том, что при отрицательном x мы часто вычитаем очень близкие значения, вот точность и страдает. Например, при вычитании 1.1111111111 и 1.00111111 - ну, там, по десятку единиц - получим нормальное 0.11. А вычитая из какого-нибудь 1111111111111111111111111111111.1111 число 1111111111111111111111111111111.0011 - получим 0, потому что точности представления чисел просто не хватит, чтоб найти разность...

Comment: а как можно это исправить ?чтобы для отрицательных тоже все верно было

Comment: Ну, еще раз - **если мы знаем, что это экспонента**, т.е. знаем, что `exp(x) = 1/exp(-x)` - то если `x<0`, считаем значение для `-x`, а потом, вычислив, берем обратное...

Comment: А если не знаем что это экспонента ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122946/discussion-between-james-and-harry).

Comment: Откровенно - не припоминаю никакого *регулярного* метода для снижения такой погрешности...

Comment: Хорошо спасибо.